# ECONNREFUSED error with meteor 1.6, mongo 3.2 and docker mac

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, docker-compose

I'm getting an ECONNREFUSED error in my meteor app so I tried going back to a built in example

```
$ git clone https://github.com/meteor/todos tst
$ cd tst
$ meteor npm install
$ meteor update
$ meteor update --all-packages
$ meteor npm install --save bcrypt
$ meteor
```

This works, so far so good.  Okay, make a docker-compose.yml

```
meteor:
  container_name: tst_meteor_1
  image: abernix/meteord:node-8-devbuild
  ports:
   - "3000:80"
  links:
   - mongo
  volumes:
   - ../output:/bundle
  environment:
   - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
   - METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
   - MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor

mongo:
  container_name: tst_mongo_1
  image: mongo:3.2-jessie
  ports:
   - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"
```

Now build the app and run it in docker

```
$ meteor build  ../output --architecture=os.linux.x86_64 --server-only
$ docker-compose --file docker-compose.yml up -d
```

Check that mongo is runnning

```
$ docker logs -f tst_mongo_1
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=012d211f6526
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.17
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 186656d79574f7dfe0831a7e7821292ab380f667
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: debian81
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-11-26T04:48:28.340+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2017-11-26T04:48:28.343+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2017-11-26T04:48:28.380+0000 I NETWORK  [HostnameCanonicalizationWorker] Starting hostname canonicalization worker
2017-11-26T04:48:28.380+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-11-26T04:48:28.381+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Yes, check that meteor is running

```
$ docker logs -f tst_meteor_1

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server
> node npm-rebuild.js


> bcrypt@1.0.3 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

[bcrypt] Success: "/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote

> fibers@2.0.0 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-57` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting
abbrev@1.1.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/abbrev
... 202 lines of node_modules
indexof@0.0.1 /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor-node-stubs/node_modules/indexof
{
  "meteor-dev-bundle": "0.0.0",
  "npm": "5.5.1",
  "ares": "1.10.1-DEV",
  "cldr": "31.0.1",
  "http_parser": "2.7.0",
  "icu": "59.1",
  "modules": "57",
  "nghttp2": "1.25.0",
  "node": "8.9.1",
  "openssl": "1.0.2m",
  "tz": "2017b",
  "unicode": "9.0",
  "uv": "1.15.0",
  "v8": "6.1.534.47",
  "zlib": "1.2.11"
}
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.

up to date in 9.48s
=> Starting meteor app on port:80

/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:313
                        throw(ex);
                        ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:336:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:280:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-mongo/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:187:49)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

And I get the ECONNREFUSED error

I'm only guessing this is a docker issue. I was running docker-machine in the past but recently upgrading to docker mac (and lots of stuff broke).

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Some other things I tried,

- moving ports
- not mapping the internal docker port to the same host port
- not using a database name (my old configuration didn't need one)
- tried creating a shared network

  ```
  version: "3.3"
  services:
    meteor:
      container_name: tst_meteor_1
      image: abernix/meteord:node-8-devbuild
      ports:
       - "3000:80"
      links:
       - mongo
      networks:
       - tst
      volumes:
       - ../output:/bundle
      environment:
       - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
       - METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
       - MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor

    mongo:
      container_name: tst_mongo_1
      image: mongo:3.2-jessie
      networks:
       - tst
      expose:
       - "27017"
      ports:
       - "127.0.0.1:27017:27017"

  networks:
    tst:
      driver: bridge
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the issue is docker now needs the container name for the mongo url

was:

```
environment:
 - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
 - METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
 - MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/meteor
```

now:

```
environment:
 - ROOT_URL=http://localhost:3000
 - METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true
 - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/meteor
```

where

```
 - MONGO_URL=mongodb://<name-of-container>:27017/meteor
```